# Mathematica automatically changes my boundary condition of Poisson equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve Poisson and drift-diffusion equations as those in simple resistors. The electron density in the device is to be solved as well as the electronic potential. The electron density is written as `rhoi + drhoe(x)`, where the `rhoi` is mean electron density and the `drhoe(x)` stands for the deviation from the mean density.

The problem was when the `rhoi == 1 x 10^16` increased to `1 x 10^18`, the *Mathematica* automatically changed the boundary condition of the potential `fi` I gave in the code, and the answer was incorrect for the `rhoi == 1x10^18` case. 
The boundary condition for `fi` is `fi[0]==3`, `fi[thick]==0`. When `rhoi==1x10^18`, the calculated answer was `fi[0]=1.5`, `fi[thick]=1.5`.

What was wrong?

Here is my code.

```
q = 1.6 10^-16;(*electron charge*)
eps = 8.85 10^-12 ;
mu = 0.1 10^-4;
diff = 0.003 10^-4;
rhoi = 1 10^18; (*in 1/m3. Mean Electron density. It is also \
the background not-moving ion density*)
thick = 1 10^-6; (*meter*)
rec = 10^6; (*recombination velocity*)
v0 = 3;
resistor = NDSolve[{
    D[fi[x], {x, 2}] + 1/eps (- q drhoe[x]) == 0,
   0 == - 
     D[(q mu (rhoi + drhoe[x]) (- D[fi[x], x] ) + 
        q diff D[drhoe[x], x]), x],
   fi[0] == v0, fi[thick] == 0,
   q mu (rhoi + drhoe[0]) (- D[fi[x], x] /. x -> 0 ) + 
     q diff (D[drhoe[x], x] /. x -> 0) == q rec drhoe[0],
   q mu (rhoi + drhoe[thick]) (- D[fi[x], x] /. x -> thick ) + 
     q diff (D[drhoe[x], x] /. x -> thick) == -q rec drhoe[thick]
   }, {drhoe, fi}, {x, 0, thick}, MaxStepFraction -> 0.001]
```

Comment: You have constants that differ by dozens of orders of magnitude; numerical results will be catastrophically bad. Please, work in natural units, where all parameters are of order one.

Answer (score 3):

We normalize the electron density to the ion density and the length to the scale of the integration region. Then the code is

```
q = 16 10^-17;(*electron charge*)eps = 885 10^-14;
mu = 10^-5;
diff = 3 10^-7;
rhoi = 1 10^18;(*in 1/m3.Mean Electron density.It is also the \
background not-moving ion density*)thick = 1 10^-6;(*meter*)rec = 
 10^6;(*recombination velocity*)v0 = 3;
k = thick^2*rhoi*q/eps ;
resistor = 
 NDSolve[{D[fi[x], {x, 2}] + k*(-drhoe[x]) == 0, 
   0 == -D[( mu (1 + drhoe[x]) (-D[fi[x], x]) + diff D[drhoe[x], x]), 
      x], fi[0] == v0, fi[1] == 0, 
   mu (1 + drhoe[0]) (-D[fi[x], x] /. x -> 0) + 
     diff (D[drhoe[x], x] /. x -> 0) == thick*rec drhoe[0], 
   mu (1 + drhoe[1]) (-D[fi[x], x] /. x -> 1) + 
     diff (D[drhoe[x], x] /. x -> 1) == - thick*rec drhoe[1]}, {drhoe,
    fi}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

When visualizing, you can go to the original units of measurement

```
{ListLinePlot[
  Table[{x*thick, First[rhoi*drhoe[x] /. resistor]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}], 
  PlotLabel -> 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[CapitalDelta]\[Rho]\), \(e\)]\)", 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", ""}, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListLinePlot[
  Table[{x*thick, First[fi[x] /. resistor]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "\[CurlyPhi]"}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad that the code turned out to be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The code works very well.  Another problem: when the parameter "thick" is placed from the right hand side to the left hand side as a denominator, an error message "Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations." came up. The equations mean the same thing but the results were different. Are there any rules to exam these?

Comment: If the code works well, then there is no sense to touch the parameters without special need.